# Non-fatal errors not showing in Crashlytics

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I was testing the [non-fatal error](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/logged-errors.html) functionality of Crashlytics and can't seem to get the recorded errors to appear in Crashlytics.

I did initialize Crashlytics in AppDelegate like this:

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

And I test send error like this (the test code is in viewDidLoad method):

```
let error = NSError(domain: "myDomain", code: 1000, userInfo: nil)
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
```

But nothing shows up in the analytics. I tried to:

- Restart application
- Disconnect from debugger and run the application several times
- Add regular crash using `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()`. In that case only the fatal crash is reported
- I waited 4 days for the data to show up

[image]

Versions:

- Crashlytics (3.8.5)
- Fabric (1.6.12)

Thanks

Comment: Hey Tomáš, can you try triggering the non-fatal from a button press and then closing and restarting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem:

The application code was embedded in a framework. My tip is that the non-fatal logs were saved in the framework's bundle not the main bundle. On the next start the main bundle was searched for logs but none was found, thus nothing was sent.

My solution was remove the app from framework as it was no longer needed in the project. I am not sure how this would be solved if you would need to keep the code in the framework.

Comment: I still have this problem. I use crashlytics via cocoapods. Can you explain a little bit more what you mean by "Remove the app from framework"?

Comment: I figured out that i didn't upload the DSYM file to my latest build.

Answer (score 1):

Run the script which uploads DSYMS to Firebase. Typically this script is not executed in debug mode - check the Build Phases tab. If you use such configuration just try in AdHoc build.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you uploaded DSYM file with your build.